# Call actions on a generic component from the child component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an Angular project with two components, a generic component where the table is defined and a component from which that table is invoked by passing the required data.

The problem is that the table generates a button to delete the record, the delete function has the component itself, not the generic component.

Is it possible to call only the component table.component and then call the function?

This is the generic component, table.component.html:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="m-3 mat-elevation-z4">

    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">

        <ng-container *ngIf="column != 'actions'">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ column | titlecase }} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element[column] }}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container *ngIf="column == 'actions'">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;let i = index" class="container-button">
            <button at-icon-button matTooltip="Delete" (click)="testDelete(dataSource.data[i])">
                <mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon>
            </button>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

This is the table.component.ts:

```
@Input('dataSource') public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
@Input('displayedColumns') public displayedColumns: string[];
```

Child component, test1.component.html:

```
<app-table-edit
  [dataSource]="dataSource"
  [displayedColumns]="displayedColumns">  
</app-table-edit>
```

test1.component.ts:

```
public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Company>;

const company = [
   {
      "name":"test2Dyn",
      "phoneNumber":null,
      "province":null
   },
   {
      "name":"test3Prov",
      "phoneNumber":null,
      "province":"Álava"
   }
]

this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(company);

public displayedColumns: string[] = ['name','phoneNumber','province','actions']
```

This is the generic service from which the endPoints are invoked, api.service.ts:

```
constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private tConstructor: { new (m: Partial<T>, ...args: unknown[]): T },
    protected apiUrl: string
  ) {}

public delete(id: number): Observable<void> {
    return this.httpClient.delete<void>(`${this.apiUrl}/${id}`);
  }
```

This is the child component's own service, test1.service.ts:

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    super(http, Company, 'http://localhost:8080/company');
  }
```

My problem: what is the best way to call the delete() service from the table button?

Comment: the typical is use `@Output`, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event), you table define `@Output() outputEmitter=new EventEmitter<any>()` and use some like `(click)="outputEmitter.emit(dataSource.data[i])"`: BTW you can use also `(click)="outputEmitter.emit(row)"`

Comment: @Eliseo I don't understand how to use the output, what I want is that the delete function is inside the test1 component, with the test1 service, and that the generic component of the table only shows a table

Comment: I add a answer to complementary the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table.component.ts can have a Output

```
@Output() onDelete=new EventEmitter<any>()
```

We use in the .html

```
    <button at-icon-button matTooltip="Delete" (click)="onDelete.emit(row)">
        <mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon>
    </button>
```

So, our test1.component.html becomes

```
<app-table-edit
  [dataSource]="dataSource"
  [displayedColumns]="displayedColumns"> 
  (onDelete)="delete($event)" 
</app-table-edit>
```

And is in test1.component.ts when we delete the element

```
delete(item:any)
{
  this.delete<void>(`${this.apiUrl}/${item.id}`).subscribe(_=>{
     //when delete we remove the element from the dataSource
```

```
     this.company.filter(x=>x.id!=item.id);
     this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(company);
```

```
     this.company=this.company.filter(x=>x.id!=item.id);
     this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.company);
  });
}
```

NOTE:**Update** code after give as valid

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but if I do, you're looking for a simple service implementation. Please read about [angular services](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) for further info.

You have to add your generic service to the constructor in table.component.ts like this:

table.component.ts:

```
constructor(private genericService: GenericService) {}
```

then you can call the delete function of that service this way.

```
 function testDelete(data)
 {
      this.genericService.delete(data.id) // note that you might access id 
                                       // differently
      .subscribe(() => (console.log(this.response)));
 }
```

here i'm logging out any responses that you migth have, but in the case of a delete you might want to show only errors. Here's a reference https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription

Comment: I can't call the service directly, because I need to pass it the model of the test1 component, or any child component that calls the table component. I think the best thing is that the function is directly in the child component and from there call the service, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

For the most generic approach, I'd suggest you to take a look at [this datatable](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/src/lib/components/datatable) which is [showcased here](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/advanced/datatables).

The code where the datatable is used is [hosted here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/advanced/datatables/datatables.component.html):

```
<bs-datatable #tabel [settings]="settings" [data]="artists" (reloadData)="loadArtists()">
  <div *bsDatatableColumn="{ sortable: true, name: 'Name' }">
    1. Artist
  </div>
  <div *bsDatatableColumn="{ sortable: true, name: 'YearStarted' }">
    2. Year started
  </div>
  <div *bsDatatableColumn="{ sortable: true, name: 'YearQuit' }">
    3. Year quit
  </div>

  <ng-template bsRowTemplate let-artist>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-nowrap">{{ artist.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-nowrap">{{ artist.yearStarted }}</td>
      <td class="text-nowrap">{{ artist.yearQuit }}</td>
      <td class="text-nowrap">
        <button (click)="doSomething()">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</bs-datatable>
```

Note that:

- `*bsDatatableColumn` is the same as `<ng-template bsDatatableColumn><div>...</div></ng-template>`. This sets the template on the `BsDatatableComponent`.
- `<ng-template bsRowTemplate let-artist>` can also be written as `<tr *bsRowTemplate="{ artist: $implicit }">`

The `BsRowTemplateDirective` takes in the `BsDatatableComponent` and `TemplateRef` (it's annotated by a `*` as explained above), and simply sets the templateRef of the `BsDatatableComponent`

```
@Directive({ selector: '[bsRowTemplate]' })
export class BsRowTemplateDirective {
  constructor(private datatableComponent: BsDatatableComponent, templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.datatableComponent.rowTemplate = templateRef;
  }
}
```

Inside the `BsDatatableComponent`, the template is projected using

```
 <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="rowTemplate; context: { $implicit: item }"></ng-container>
```

However, I fear that refactoring your code snippet to move the rowTemplate to the consuming component will not be a walk in the park.

Comment: I'm seeing it but I don't understand how to adapt it to my project. What I want to achieve is to be able to call the delete function from the test1 component, instead of calling the function inside the table component.

Comment: Note that in my example `doSomething` IS IN FACT defined in the consuming component. But as I said, refactoring the given code snippet will not be easy